# Docker entrypoint returns different results from running script manually

Tags: bash, docker, email, containers, docker-entrypoint

I have a container that runs an SQL query and then sends an email based on the results.

```
#!/bin/bash
AMOUNT=$(mysql -h foo -u foo -pfoo  foo < order-check.sql | sed 's/amount//'| cut -f1 -d ".")
if [ $AMOUNT -eq 0 ]
then
sendmail foo@bar.com < /app/order-check-email.txt
sleep 30
echo `cat /var/log/exim4/mainlog`
else
sendmail foo@bar.com < /app/order-check-email-ok.txt
fi
```

If I exec into the container and run

```
sh app/order-check.sh
```

Then the script runs fine and sends out the email.

I am now trying to run the script on startup

```
FROM namshi/smtp
ENV MAILNAME foo.com
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y default-mysql-client
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN chmod 744 /app/order-check.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/app/order-check.sh"]
```

However, I now get an error on sending of the email

```
2022-10-06 14:42:26 1ogS4w-00000B-Of <= root@28785892f941 U=root P=local S=383 2022-10-06 14:42:26 1ogS4w-00000B-Of Dockerfile authorized_keys order-check-email-ok.txt order-check-email.txt order-check.sh order-check.sql foo@bar.co.uk R=nonlocal: Mailing to remote domains not supported 2022-10-06 14:42:26 1ogS4w-00000E-Pe <= <> R=1ogS4w-00000B-Of U=Debian-exim P=local S=1621 2022-10-06 14:42:26 1ogS4w-00000B-Of Completed 2022-10-06 14:42:26 1ogS4w-00000E-Pe => /var/mail/mail <root@28785892f941> R=mail4root T=address_file 2022-10-06 14:42:26 1ogS4w-00000E-Pe Completed
```

Why is it different from running entrypoint rather than manual and how can I fix it?

Comment: when you enter the container to manually execute - are you entering as root (or other user with sudo privs)?  what do the permissions on `order-check.sh` look like?  perhaps your entry point needs to look like `ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "sudo /app/order-check.sh"]`

Comment: rwxr--r root:root, I tried adding your entry point also USER root but still the same problem

Comment: When you use the `docker exec` debug shell to run the script, what is the main container process?  A container only runs one process and isn't normally running an SMTP daemon, and it's possible that `sendmail` might have some trouble because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I needed to run the entrypoint script that was on the image first

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c" , "/bin/entrypoint.sh && /app/order-summery.sh"]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).